# Python child process silently crashes when issuing an HTTP request

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, nltk, python-multiprocessing

I'm running into an issue when combining multiprocessing, requests (or urllib2) and nltk. Here is a very simple code:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> Process(target=lambda: pprint(
        requests.get('https://api.github.com'))).start()
>>> <Response [200]>  # this is the response displayed by the call to `pprint`.
```

A bit more details on what this piece of code does:

1. Import a few required modules
2. Start a child process
3. Issue an HTTP GET request to 'api.github.com' from the child process
4. Display the result

This is working great. The problem comes when importing nltk:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> Process(target=lambda: pprint(
        requests.get('https://api.github.com'))).start()
>>> # nothing happens!
```

After having imported NLTK, the requests actually silently crashes the thread (if you try with a named function instead of the lambda function, adding a few `print` statement before and after the call, you'll see that the execution stops right on the call to `requests.get`)
Does anybody have any idea what in NLTK could explain such behavior, and how to get overcome the issue?

Here are the version I'm using:

```
$> python --version
Python 2.7.5
$> pip freeze | grep nltk
nltk==2.0.5
$> pip freeze | grep requests
requests==2.2.1
```

I'm running Mac OS X v. 10.9.5.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not related to SSL, replacing the github api URL by 'http://google.com' doesn't change the behaviour with/without nltk imported.

Comment: The problem is not related to `requests` either. When replacing the call to `requests.get` by `req = urllib2.Request('http://google.com'); handler = urllib2.urlopen(req); print handler.getcode()` the problem stays the same.

Comment: Upgrading nltk to the last version did not fix the issue either...

Comment: Try doing the same thing without multiprocessing, i.e., perform it in same process and see what happens.

Comment: This works, the issue is specific to the request being sent from the child process.
This bug has already been reported 2 months ago: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/947. However, the version of NLTK I'm running has been released in Nov 2012, I'm surprised nobody noticed it sooner.

Comment: Haha, it seems using Nltk and Python Requests in a child process is rare. Try using Thread instead of Process, I was having exactly same issue with some other library and Requests and replacing Process with Thread worked for me. Let me know, if it works, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: This will work as well ;-)
You can post it as an answer, this may be useful for other people. I won't accept it tho, because with threads you introduce the limitation of the GIL. I agree that it is not relevant for this simple example but in larger applications it may be a concern (and it is one for my actually)

Comment: have you tried updating your NLTK version?

Comment: A similar thing happened to me when importing `ipdb`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877491/python-multiprocessing-process-is-killed-by-http-request-if-ipdb-is-imported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating your python libraries and python should resolve the problem:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ pip freeze | grep nltk
nltk==3.0.3
alvas@ubi:~$ pip freeze | grep requests
requests==2.7.0
alvas@ubi:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
alvas@ubi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

From code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import nltk
import time


def child_fn():
    print "Fetch URL"
    import urllib2
    print urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com").read()[:100]
    print "Done"


while True:
    child_process = Process(target=child_fn)
    child_process.start()
    child_process.join()
    print "Child process returned"
    time.sleep(1)
```

[out]:

```
Fetch URL
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="de"><head><meta content
Done
Child process returned
Fetch URL
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="de"><head><meta content
Done
Child process returned
Fetch URL
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="de"><head><meta content
Done
Child process returned
```

From code:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> Process(target=lambda: pprint(
...         requests.get('https://api.github.com'))).start()
>>> <Response [200]>

>>> import nltk
>>> Process(target=lambda: pprint(
...         requests.get('https://api.github.com'))).start()
>>> <Response [200]>
```

---

It should work with `python3` too:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>> import requests
>>> Process(target=lambda: print(requests.get('https://api.github.com'))).start()
>>> 
>>> <Response [200]>

>>> import nltk
>>> Process(target=lambda: print(requests.get('https://api.github.com'))).start()
>>> <Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems using Nltk and Python Requests in a child process is rare. Try using Thread instead of Process, I was having exactly same issue with some other library and Requests and replacing Process with Thread worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue still seems not solved.
https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/947
I think this is a serious issue (unless you are playing with NLTK, doing POCs and trying out models, not actual apps) 
I am running the NLP pipelines in RQ workers (http://python-rq.org/)

```
nltk==3.2.1
requests==2.9.1
```

Comment: Ask a new question if needed. This looks like a comment and not an answer to the actual question.

Comment: Sorry it's a comment. I still don't have 50 reputation to comment :)

Comment: @SasindaRukshan you now have enough reputation to move this to a comment.